# How to open URL in maximized mode in Application Display Template?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I have created and [**ADT**](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-application-display-templates) (**Application Display Template**) for Asset Publisher which displays web-contents. If a link is clicked the web-content should open in maximized mode.

```
<#if entries?has_content>
    <#list entries as entry>
        <#assign renderer = entry.getAssetRenderer() />
        <#assign className = renderer.getClassName() />
        <#if className == "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle">
            <#assign journalArticle = renderer.getArticle() />
            <#assign document = saxReaderUtil.read(journalArticle.getContentByLocale(locale.toString())) />

            <#assign assetURL = assetPublisherHelper.getAssetViewURL(renderRequest, renderResponse,entry) />

            <div class="molisana-product">
                <a href="${assetURL}">
                    <h3 class="product-title">
                        ${entry.getTitle(locale)}
                    </h3>
                </a>
            </div>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

The important bit is :

```
<#assign assetURL = assetPublisherHelper.getAssetViewURL(renderRequest, renderResponse,entry) />
```

I tried with **setWindowState** `<a href="${assetURL.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED)}">` but doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try appending `&p_p_state=maximized` at the end of `assetURL`? As `assetURL` is a `String`, so you can append `windowState` parameter as `<a href="${assetURL}&p_p_state=maximized">`

Comment: Other way is to use `$portletURLFactory` like in this [***link***](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12577803)